# Http and Https communicating issues

Tags: http, https

Trying to upload a media (video / image) for iphone and android, from one domain using HTTPs to another HTTP. Cant change both to a single protocol as both have different environments which cant be changed apparently.

Everything's working fine on iOS but Android is not doing the uploading thing.

Getting following error on Android chrome :

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://*****' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://*****'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Post the errors; only then we could help you on this :)

Comment: Getting this error on Android chrome. Mixed Content: The page at 'https://*****' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://*****'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Make me clear, 1. You are trying to upload an image from HTTPS application to HTTP and I didn't understand this part "Everything's working fine on iOS" So, you have tried it in a iOS native browser??? Please do reply with your code, only then you could get it clearly and quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

When the main page is https, then insecure (http) request are mostly blocked.

The best way to avoid mixed content errors is to use https for everything.